# Including Makefile from config.m4

Tags: makefile, autoconf, php-extension

I am writing a PHP extension. `config.m4` generates the Makefile, but I want to include, at the begin of this Makefile another Makefile. (e.g.: `"-include Makefile.local"`).

I don't want to do it in the `Makefile` itself, since `configure` will recreate it and erase my changes when invoked.

How can I do it from `config.m4`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in `config.m4`:

```
AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS_PRE([cat >Makefile.tmp <<EOF
-include MyInclude1
-include MyInclude2
EOF
cat Makefile >> Makefile.tmp
mv -f Makefile.tmp Makefile])
```

Your `Makefile` should now look like:

```
-include MyInclude1
-include MyInclude2
srcdir = /path/to/source/dir
...
```

...after running `configure`.